# How much did the duralumin structure of the Shuttle weigh?

Tags: space-shuttle, structural-design

I am trying to understand the benefit of a Shuttle type "cold structure" Vs a Starship type structure. Google tells me that the Shuttle TPS weighed 8,574.4kg, and the duralumin has a 50-80% greater strength to weight than stainless steel. But how much duralumin was in the Shuttle?

Comment: A note: "Duralumin" often refers to a specific aluminum alloy or family of alloys, which I am under the impression were possibly obsolete in aerospace applications by the Shuttle era. Do you mean Duralumin specifically, or structural aluminum alloys generally?

Comment: @ikrase agreed, "duralumin" is a term I associate with old science fiction stories. According to wikipedia it's an obsolete term for Al-Cu alloys, which *were* used in shuttle, mostly Al 2024. But it's not a term we ever used. And no idea how to get a mass just for the airframe. Perhaps someone will turn it up, you never know.

Comment: @OrganicMarble given that the Shuttle used 4 allots, which have different strengths depending on temper, I'm considering deleting this question because it is pointless